# vba access: add to row duplicated id

Tags: vba, ms-access, duplicates

I'm a newbie in access and english, so bear with me while I try to explain you the situation.

I have a table similar to this

```
id     name    description
1      foo      
2      bar
3      foo
4      foo
```

And I want the description column like this

```
id     name    description
1      foo      3;4
2      bar
3      foo      1;4
4      foo      1;3
```

The idea is to identify where is duplicated the name, but keeping the amount of rows (in other words, without doing a GROUP BY).
It's something similar to this topic: [Update duplicate rows with duplicated found id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561766/update-duplicate-rows-with-duplicated-found-id)

The question is, how can I apply that solution through VBA?

Please tell me if you need more details.

Comment: What do you need to write to the new column? A count of duplicates, or the PK(s) of the duplicate(s)?

Comment: The PK(s) of the duplicated, I've modified the issue to be more specific. Thanks!